# Query with two reverse relationships in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models

If I have these Django models:

```py
class ModelA(Model):
    pass

class ModelB(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(ModelA, ...)
    d = ForeignKey(ModelD, ...)
    r = IntegerField()
    q = IntegerField()

class ModelC(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(ModelA, ...)
    d = ForeignKey(ModelD, ...)
    r = IntegerField()

class ModelD(Model):
    pass
```

How can I do a Django ORM query equivalent to this:

```sql
select ModelB.q, ModelA.id, ModelD.id
from ModelA
join ModelB on ModelB.a_id=ModelA.id
left join ModelC on (ModelC.a_id=ModelB.a_id and ModelC.r=ModelB.r
    and ModelC.d_id=ModelB.d_id)
join ModelD on ModelB.d_id=ModelD.id
where ModelC.id is null
```

I.e. get `ModelB`s whose fields don't match any `ModelC`s, where both `ModelB` and `ModelC` have foreign keys to two other models.

Comment: Have you tried to write any Django ORM queries to handle this? What were they?

Comment: @ChidG Just raw SQL